# Error Decoding QrCode image file using qrcode-reader [React-Native]

Tags: javascript, react-native, buffer, qr-code, expo

I'm using [qrcode-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-reader) to decode qr-code from saved image file
First I get image-data in base64 format using Expo ImagePicker
Second I use [BufferFrom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-from) to get image buffer and pass it decode function

The issue is no what image iI tried to use I always get this Error:
Couldn't find enough finder patterns:0 patterns found
Hint: All images I use are decoded successfully using Camera Scan.

```
const {
  width,
  height,
  uri,
  base64
} = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: 'Images',
  aspect: [1, 1],
  base64: true
});

var qr = new QrCode();
qr.callback = function(err, value) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error Decoding', err);
  }

  console.log('Value', value);
};

qr.decode({ width, height }, bufferFrom(base64, 'base64'));
```

Comment: If you are using Expo, then you could use their own QR-scanner. Maybe that works better in your case. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/sdk/bar-code-scanner

Comment: Thank you your help :) ... but the app I'm trying to build requires both Camera-Scaning and Decoding from file

I'm done with the Camera-Scanning part (Thanks to Expo) ... and now struggling with File-Decoding